# OSX Terminal - Search full output for string

Tags: bash, macos, shell, terminal, scripting

I'm running several (nested) scripts in a row and each of these has a very distinctive success message. After all scripts are done I would like to search the full terminal output for these specific strings to find out if all scripts have completed successfully.

How can I search the terminal output via bash?

Comment: Suggest writing the entire script run to a file using `cmd1; cmd2 > file` and later use the _file_ for post-processing.

Comment: Provide a minimal verifiable input and expected output.

Answer (score 1):

```
(cmd1;cmd2;..;cmdn)|grep '\(message1\|message2\|..\|messagen\)'
```